# VB Script to Check, Download, and Install Windows Updates from Microsoft with Exclusions in a text file

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that will check, download, and install windows updates.  Got the basic script from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/VB-Script-to-Check-and-620579cd#content.

I'm trying to exclude specific updates by reading a text file containing the fully qualified name of the update.  If I only have 1 line in my text file, it works great.  When I have multiple line, the script shows multiple results of the update being excluded and also added.  It's probably just the placement of my For Next loops but I'm banging my head.  Here's the section of my script I'm having problems with:

```
'Create collection of updates to download
WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Creating collection of updates to download:"
Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source\Scripts\CheckUpdates\CheckUpdates\ExcludedUpdates.txt", ForReading) 
Const ForReading = 1 
Dim arrExclusions() 
i = 0 
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
Redim Preserve arrExclusions(i) 
arrExclusions(i) = objFile.ReadLine 
i = i + 1 
Loop 
objFile.Close
For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
addThisUpdate = false
For each strExcludedUpdate in arrExclusions
    If update.Title = strExcludedUpdate Then
        Wscript.Echo I + 1 & "> EXCLUDED: " & update.Title 
        addThisUpdate = false
    Else
        If update.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> Skipping: " & update.Title & _
        " because it requires user input"
        Else
            If update.EulaAccepted = false Then
                WScript.Echo vbCrLf & I + 1 & "> NOTE: " & update.Title & _
                " has a license agreement that must be accepted:"
                WScript.Echo update.EulaText
                WScript.Echo vbCrLF & "Do you accept this license agreement? (Y/N)"
                strInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
                'strInput = "Y"     'remove remark to auto answer Y (Yes) without user input.
                WScript.Echo 
                If (strInput = "Y" or strInput = "y") Then
                    update.AcceptEula()
                    addThisUpdate = true
                Else
                    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> ----- Skipping: " & update.Title & _
                    " because the license agreement was declined"
                End If
            Else
                addThisUpdate = true
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
If addThisUpdate = true Then
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> ADDING: " & update.Title 
    updatesToDownload.Add(update)
End If
    Next

    If updatesToDownload.Count = 0 Then
      WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "No applicable updates to download. Closing in 5 seconds..."
WScript.Sleep 5000
      WScript.Quit
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your Const for Reading should be above the line that is opening the file.
2. I wasn't 100% sure what you wanted to do in that for loop, so I have created an alternate version that seems to do what you want; I've split the scan for excluded files and then retested addThisUpdate and performed the rest. Unfortunately, on the machine I was testing there are no updates available to test the EULA stuff with! It runs, does not produce duplicates. I hope this helps. **I didn't paste the entire script**

---

```
Const ForReading = 1 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source\Scripts\CheckUpdates\CheckUpdates\ExcludedUpdates.txt", ForReading) 

Dim arrExclusions() 
i = 0 
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
    Redim Preserve arrExclusions(i) 
    arrExclusions(i) = objFile.ReadLine 
    i = i + 1 
Loop 
objFile.Close
For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    addThisUpdate = true
    For each strExcludedUpdate in arrExclusions
        If update.Title = strExcludedUpdate Then
            Wscript.Echo I + 1 & "> EXCLUDED: " & update.Title 
            addThisUpdate = false
        End If
    Next
    If addThisUpdate = True then
        If update.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput = true Then
            WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> Skipping: " & update.Title & _
            " because it requires user input"
        Else
            If update.EulaAccepted = false Then
                WScript.Echo vbCrLf & I + 1 & "> NOTE: " & update.Title & _
                " has a license agreement that must be accepted:"
                WScript.Echo update.EulaText
                WScript.Echo vbCrLF & "Do you accept this license agreement? (Y/N)"
                strInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
                'strInput = "Y"     'remove remark to auto answer Y (Yes) without user input.
                WScript.Echo 
                If (strInput = "Y" or strInput = "y") Then
                    update.AcceptEula()
                    addThisUpdate = true
                Else
                    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> ----- Skipping: " & update.Title & _
                    " because the license agreement was declined"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If addThisUpdate = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> ADDING: " & update.Title 
        updatesToDownload.Add(update)
    End If
Next

If updatesToDownload.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "No applicable updates to download. Closing in 5 seconds..."
    WScript.Sleep 5000
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Splitting out the scan for Excluded updates did the trick.  My test machine actually has a combination of the different updates available to it (User Input Required and EULA) so I was able to test the different scenarios.  The only additions I had to make were to set addThisUpdate = false if user input required and if EULA declined and it works the way I need it to.  Thanks very much!